# How does 参｛まい｝る relate to love?

Tags: meaning, keigo

Google translate lists "be madly in love" and "be infatuated" as alternate translations for 参｛まい｝る.

When I saw it I was like, huh?

I searched 参｛まい｝る　意味｛いみ｝ on Google too and the first couple sites did list things relating to love, but I didn't understand it that well.

So, could someone paint this picture for me about why 参｛まい｝る has these definitions and in what contexts it would fit those definitions?

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW the "in love with" sense of 参る is a kind of old slang that is obsolete today.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A handful of metaphorical uses of 参る come from a general idea of leaving and yielding to someone else.

These include

- to be defeated (often in the form of 参った)
- to be troubled, perplexed
- to die
- to fall in love (the idea being they stole your heart)

Source https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E5%8F%82%E3%82%8B